# MS Word - How to number tables?

Tags: ms-word

I want my tables each have a number above it. Like `Table 3-2 [Table Name]`.

Now the closest thing I can achieve, is to use `List Style`. But the strange thing is that the number from table doesn't change, so the table number would count on and on, like `Table 1-1000`, rather than `Table 3-3`. It doesn't recognize the chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Create the numbers first (bullet points) and then copy and paste the tables into each point from another document.

You can also do it from the index. First create index and there you can number them and tag it to the corresponding table.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for it? My language is not english, so for manipulate Word, I need more specifications.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/tables-i-create-and-format-basic-tables-RZ001200716.aspx

This will be of help. It's directly from MS and it's very very easy to understand.